# Accessing values from a two dimensional initialized array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
int a[][30]={{2, 16},{4, 8},{5, 16, 21},{2,6,3,5,6}};
```

Since the size of the second dimension is varying. If I want to access something like for a particular value of `i`(first dimension), access all `j` values(2nd dimension), how do I write that statement?

What I thought was:

```
for(int j=0;j<30;j++)
  a[i][j]=some operation;
```

but its unnecessarily looping till 30 which is the max value. What's the efficient way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler does not keep any information about how many values were in the braced initializer.  Instead, it fills the "missing" values with zeros.

So these two are equivalent:

```
int a[][4] = {{2, 16},{4, 8, 5}};
int a[][4] = {{2, 16, 0, 0}, {4, 8, 5, 0}};
```

If you know that none of the "actual" data elements are zero, you can stop your loop when you find a zero element.  Otherwise, you'll need to set up the data differently.

Answer (score 2):

The size of both dimensions is fixed. The outer dimension has size `4` and the inner has size `30`.

If you iterate over the inner dimension, then you will print lots of zeros, as that is what you initialize the remaining integers that aren't explicitly initialized to.

You seem to want this:

```
std::vector<int> a[] = { 
   boost::list_of(2)(16), 
   boost::list_of(4)(8), 
   boost::list_of(5)(16)(21), 
   boost::list_of(2)(6)(3)(5)(6) 
};
```

Comment: Ok. Cant I just iterate through only that number of times in inner loop as number of elements? like if I want to access all members for a[2], is there any way to know the size of inner loop for that i?

Comment: @imaginatives, `a[2]` has 30 members. Most of them are zero. So sure there is a way to know the size of it: The size is statically known. A multidimensional array can't have the size of inner dimensions of the same depth differ. You need to use dynamic allocation for this (in other words, `std::vector` as a convenient wrapper), or construct some own protocol, like "the first integer in `a[N]` specifies the number of elements that are relevant" or some such.